# Colloquial expression for a cigarette

Tags: single-word-requests

I was looking for a colloquial way to call a cigarette in English, and the only one that I found was "ciggie".

Can you think of a different one?

Or is the "ciggie" what native speakers would actually use?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47212/discussion-on-question-by-cornejo-colloquial-expression-for-a-cigarette).

Comment: Do you want terms used *by smokers*, or would terms used by non-smokers also work? I think existing answers cover the obvious choices for the former, but there are also a bunch of the latter, at least in the US where smoking is now widely condemned. (Widely enough that I think even some smokers sometimes use the more derogatory terms.)

Answer (score 6):

How about *smoke*?

> Can you spare a *smoke*?
>
> Got any *smokes*?

M-W:

> [*smoke*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smoke): a
> cigarette, cigar, etc. : something that people smoke

Comment: In my experience, 'tab' is the most common. "You gotta tab mate?", "Gizza tab", "I need a tab".

Comment: @grateful Interesting. Where do you live? I live in the States, have smoked for years, and have never heard that term.

Comment: @grateful: In colloquial parlance about drugs, *tab* in AmE used to mean a bit of LSD (*tab of acid*), but otherwise it means nothing, that I'm aware of, wrt other drugs.

Comment: @Drew That I've heard.

Answer (score 1):

Smoking (or hacking) a [***dart***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dart) is a term I have heard in recent years in this area (Ontario, Canada).

Answer (score 0):

@RichardKayser is correct for an unused cigarette. [Butt](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/coffin_nail/synonyms) is commonly used for a used one, similar to the British [dog end](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/dog-end).

> "A small part of a cigarette that is left after smoking".

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cigarette+butt)

Answer (score 0):

When I was young "fag" was *the* slang term in the US, at least in the schoolyards I frequented. I would guess that the term dropped from common use (to mean "cigarette") about 30 years ago, however, as the term took on the (derogatory) meaning of "homosexual".

(I'm recalling that both senses of the word are related to "faggot", which is a bundle of sticks, though I've never fully understood why that word is associated with homosexuality.)

(If one were writing a book set in the US in the 50s, "fag" would be the word to use.  But it would be unsuited for more recent contexts.)

In terms of current vernacular, "butt", "smoke", and "cig" are probably the best one can do for US terms, unless we can get a smoking teenager in here to update us on the slang.

Answer (score 0):

Including "ciggie," I've heard:

-Square

-Drag

-Dart (Canadian)

-Fag (British)

-Bean

-Round

I'm a non-smoker.